# How to print the keys from another dictionary and value from deep nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

My Dictionary is below.How to print the keys from another dictionary and value from deep nested dict in Python?

```
my_nested_dict = {"global": {"peers": {"15.1.1.1": {"remote_id": "15.1.1.1", "address_family": {"ipv4": {"sent_prefixes": 1, "received_prefixes": 4, "accepted_prefixes": 4}}, "remote_as": 65002, "uptime": 13002, "is_enabled": True, "is_up": True, "description": "== R3 BGP Neighbor ==", "local_as": 65002}}, "router_id": "15.1.1.2"}}
filtered_list = ['peers', 'remote_id', 'remote_as', 'uptime']
filtered_map_dict = {'peers':'pe', 'remote_id':'id', 'remote_as':'as', 'uptime':'up'}
def seek_keys(d, key_list):
     for k, v in d.items():
            if k in key_list:
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    print(k + ": " + list(v.keys())[0])
                else:
                    print(k + ": " + str(v))
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                seek_keys(v, key_list)

seek_keys(my_nested_dict, filtered_list)
```

**My Output:**

```
peers: 15.1.1.1
remote_id: 15.1.1.1
remote_as: 65002
uptime: 13002
```

**Expected output:**

```
pe: 15.1.1.1
id: 15.1.1.1
as: 65002
up: 13002
```

Comment: Just print `filtered_map_dict[k]` instead of `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print `filter_list[k]` instead of simple `k`. I have written an example code which provides the expected output.

**Code:**

```
def seek_keys(d, key_list, filter_list):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in key_list:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                print(filter_list[k] + ": " + list(v.keys())[0])
            else:
                print(filter_list[k] + ": " + str(v))
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            seek_keys(v, key_list, filter_list)


seek_keys(my_nested_dict, filtered_list, filtered_map_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
pe: 15.1.1.1
id: 15.1.1.1
as: 65002
as: 13002  # It should be "as" based on your filtered_map_dict. (Not "up" as you have written in your question.)
```

If you change your `filtered_map_dict` to:

```
filtered_map_dict = {"peers": "pe", "remote_id": "id", "remote_as": "as", "uptime": "up"}
```

The output will be exactly what you want as you can see below.

```
>>> python3 test.py 
pe: 15.1.1.1
id: 15.1.1.1
as: 65002
up: 13002
```